# middle number in array with two methods java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

How do I get my code to find the middle number? Whenever I run my code, I can enter my desired numbers but it doesn’t tell me what the middle number is.

```
 public static int middleArray(int values[])
 {
   //reading numbers into the array
  int [] ma = new int [0];
  int middleArray;
  if(values.length % 2 == 0)
  {
      int num1=(values.length-1)/2;
      int num2 = values.length/2;

      middleArray = ( values[num1] + values[num2])/ 2;
      return middleArray;
    }  
         else
     {
        int num = (values.length - 1) / 2;
        middleArray = values[num];

     }
       return middleArray;
     }
    public static void main() {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers to determine middle 
   number");
   int middleArray = s.nextInt();


  }
 }
```

Comment: Please include your code as *text*, not a screenshot

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you pasted the text into the question instead of a screenshot. :)

Comment: The scanner will read in an int at a time, and you should be building an array that you will pass into your method to find the middle number. Right now in your main method you are just reading each int, but not doing anything with it. Your ending line should look something like int middleNum = middleArray(numArray); where numArray is the array you build with the Scanner.  Then you would print that number I am guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, im having trouble following it, and it looks like you did some wrong math calculating some things

```
      int num1=(values.length-1)/2;
      int num2 = values.length/2;

      middleArray = ( values[num1] + values[num2])/ 2;
```

You added the length of the array to itself, and then divided by 2. Essentially cancelling out adding the array length twice. On top of this you never even called your function inside the main loop, nor do you have a way to close your input.

A functioning version of your code for taking the median of a set of unsorted numbers would be this (I got rid of the scanner because that kind of user input gets complicated, i dont think youre at that level yet):

```
    public static double takeMiddleOfArr(int values[]) {
        double output = 0; //Initialize output
        if(values.length % 2 != 0) { //See if the array is even or odd
            output = values[(int)Math.floor(values.length/2)]; //If odd just output middle element
        } else {
            double mid = values.length/2.0; //Finds middle element of array
            output = (values[(int)(mid-1)]+values[(int)(mid)])/2; //If even take avg of middle elements
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,20,6,3,2,1}; //Input array
        System.out.println(takeMiddleOfArr(array)); //Prints outout
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic in original code calculation to get middle numbers is (values.length-1)/2 instead it should be [(values.length/2)-1]. If there are two numbers then those two numbers will be printed as middle numbers. Please try below code with sample test results.

Code:

```
public class middleNum {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int[] first= new int[] {1,2};
        int[] second= new int[] {1,2,3};
        int[] third= new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        int[] fourth= new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMiddleNum(first)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMiddleNum(second)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMiddleNum(third)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getMiddleNum(fourth)));
        }

    public static int[] getMiddleNum(int[] nums) {
        int[] ma;
        if (nums.length %2 == 0) {
            // if the array length is even then there are two middle numbers
            ma = new int[2];
            ma[0] = nums[(nums.length/2) - 1];
            ma[1] = nums[nums.length/2];

        } else {
            // if the array length is odd then there is one middle number
            ma = new int[1];
            ma[0] = nums[nums.length/2];
        }
        return ma;
    }
}

Output:

[1,2]
[2]
[2,3]
[3]
```